# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found

Tags: java, linux, flutter, android-studio

when i run sdkmanager command from terminal it prints out this error

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found
```

sdkmanager is a command from android studio command tools kit

i tried
`set JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee`
but it doesnt seem to fix it

Os:Arch Linux

how can i fix this?